# How can I raise an event from anywhere in my WPF application?

Tags: wpf

I have a base page, BasePage, that raises an event that displays messages to the user.  Works great on all pages derived from BasePage.  I want to do the same thing from user controls, but they don't inherit from BasePage.

What I want is a central place that I can call from anywhere and in that code it will raise an event.  Where is a good place to put this code:

```
    public void DisplayMessage(string message)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new MessageNotificationEventArgs(MessageNotificationEvent, message));
    }
```

so that I can call it from anywhere? RaiseEvent is in the UIElement class, so it needs to go somewhere that is a UIElement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using events to do this, you should be using Commanding - Josh Smith wrote a great article on this: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/understanding-routed-commands/

Comment: Except that, in a non-trivial application, it just isn't enough.  Not everything lives in the same visual tree, and in that case, the command won't work.  They are only a partial solution to the problem and not a sufficient mechanism for communication between arbitrary components in an application.  Chris' answer below is a better approach.

Comment: Only RoutedCommands have the visual tree restrictions. You have to remember, the "Event Aggregator" approach is only one step away from a global variable - yeah, it will work, and the decoupling provided by the aggregator is better than a global variable, but you should still strive to solve it in a less brute-force way.

Comment: I think I'm just frustrated trying to find a simple approach to communicate between components.  Separation of view and logic is great, but I have yet to develop even a moderately simple app in WPF that doesn't run into this issue.

Answer (score 3):

One solution to problem is to use an [Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html). The pattern itself is platform independent.

Jeremy Miller has a post about building your own event aggregator [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/01/11/build-your-own-cab-extensible-pub-sub-event-aggregator-with-generics.aspx).

**However, [Composite WPF](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF) (formerly Prism) does this and it's optimized for WPF.** The specifics can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707857.aspx).